# hybrid android app is not working after build

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, interface, hybrid-mobile-app

i have an application created on Android Studio that uses JavaScript Interface ( addJavascriptInterface ).
And everything works perfect while running on Android Studio build-in emulator pushing "green PLAY button" (Shift+F10), but when i'm trying to build this app into APK-file (it doesn't matter is it signed or not), nothing works (it seems like it stuck ).

i found that problem is in calling Java function through JavaScript interface

```
    var saved_lang = window.ob.readfile3('lang.txt');
```

somehow **.readfile3()** "is not a function" any more

i was looking through different forums and sites, watched lots of youtube videos, but i couldn't find at once how to fix old code to it continue work properly.

---

**here are some details**

from app/build.gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 27
```

the very beginning of onCreate class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(myObject,"ob");

    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    ...
}
```

and here is MyObject class (part of it)

```
 class MyObject{

    private MainActivity ma;

    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    private String writeConfigString(String myStr){
        writeFile(myStr);
        return "file is written";
    }

    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    private String readfile3(String fileName){
        String out = readFile2(fileName);
        return out;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in a few days of searching and testing i found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) that something have changed in the last version of Android API and i tried to do **PUBLIC** all JavascriptInterface methods of MyObject class... like this:

```
 class MyObject{

    public MainActivity ma;

    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    public String writeConfigString(String myStr){
        writeFile(myStr);
        return "file is written";
    }

    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    public String readfile3(String fileName){
        //return MainActivity.email;
        String out = readFile2(fileName);
        return out;
    }
    ...
}
```

and everything is working fine now =)

P.S. i hope this solution will help someone else.